# Hive metastore database details missing in hive-site.xml

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh, hive-metastore

We are using CDH 5.4.6. I am able to find Hive Metastore details in Cloudera UI .

But I am trying to find the same details on configuartion file.

I can only find `hive.metastore.uris` parameter in `/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml` . conf file hive-site.xml supposed to have `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL` / `ConnectionDriverName` / `ConnectionUserName` / `ConnectionPassword`. Where can I find those details?

```
<!--Autogenerated by Cloudera Manager-->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://xxxxx.com:9083</value>
  </property>
```

Answer (score 1):

JDO details are only applicable to Hive Metastore. So, for security reasons they are not included in client configuration version of `hive-site.xml`. The settings that you see in Cloudera Manager UI are stored in Cloudera Manager's database. CM retrieves and adds those values dynamically to a special server-side `hive-site.xml` which it generates before HMS process is started. That file can be seen in configuration directory `/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/nnn-hive-HIVEMETASTORE/` on the node running HMS role (with proper permissions; `nnn` here is an incremental process counter).

By the way, CDH 5.4.6 has been EOL'ed for ages. Why aren't you upgrading?